# Minify = True and Debuggable = False causes NullPointerException crash?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, obfuscation

I have looked into all the other similar questions on StackOverflow and so far none of it is helpful. I am fairly new to Android and especially the minifying process.

The Release.apk is having a crash that the Debug.apk is not, but however when I try to go and debug the Release.apk by doing:

```
debuggable true
minifyEnabled false
```

The bug never happens??? Here is the stack trace:

```
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:69)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:77)
        at libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl.getGenericComponentType(GenericArrayTypeImpl.java:32)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:10)
        at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:4)
        at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:2)
        at os$a.<init>(IndicatorDefinitionsTask.java:1)
        at os.i(IndicatorDefinitionsTask.java:7)
        at com.someCompany.XXX.a.M2(AddIndicatorDialog.java:14)
        at og.P2(DialogFragment.java:4)
        at og.m1(DialogFragment.java:3)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.O1(Fragment.java:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.k.f(FragmentStateManager.java:4)
        at androidx.fragment.app.k.m(FragmentStateManager.java:19)
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.e0(FragmentManager.java:34)
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.g1(FragmentManager.java:10)
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.b0(FragmentManager.java:4)
        at androidx.fragment.app.i$g.run(FragmentManager.java:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.someCompany.network.IndicatorDefinitionsTask$IndicatorDefinition
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:77) 
        at libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl.getGenericComponentType(GenericArrayTypeImpl.java:32) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:10) 
        at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:4) 
        at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:2) 
        at os$a.<init>(IndicatorDefinitionsTask.java:1) 
        at os.i(IndicatorDefinitionsTask.java:7) 
        at com.someCompany.XXX.a.M2(AddIndicatorDialog.java:14) 
        at og.P2(DialogFragment.java:4) 
        at og.m1(DialogFragment.java:3) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.O1(Fragment.java:1) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.k.f(FragmentStateManager.java:4) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.k.m(FragmentStateManager.java:19) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.e0(FragmentManager.java:34) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.g1(FragmentManager.java:10) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.b0(FragmentManager.java:4) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i$g.run(FragmentManager.java:1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.someCompany.network.IndicatorDefinitionsTask$IndicatorDefinition
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:77) 
        at libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl.getGenericComponentType(GenericArrayTypeImpl.java:32) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:10) 
        at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:4) 
        at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:2) 
        at os$a.<init>(IndicatorDefinitionsTask.java:1) 
        at os.i(IndicatorDefinitionsTask.java:7) 
        at com.someCompany.XXX.a.M2(AddIndicatorDialog.java:14) 
        at og.P2(DialogFragment.java:4) 
        at og.m1(DialogFragment.java:3) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.O1(Fragment.java:1) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.k.f(FragmentStateManager.java:4) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.k.m(FragmentStateManager.java:19) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.e0(FragmentManager.java:34) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.g1(FragmentManager.java:10) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i.b0(FragmentManager.java:4) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.i$g.run(FragmentManager.java:1) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664) 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String gx0.k()' on a null object reference
        at com.someCompany.XXX.MainActivity$g.getView(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2067)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:793)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:855)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1838)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2184)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:18)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3475)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2943)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8177)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I am essentially clicking on a button in a fragment that is not even in MainActivity but in another Activity and the crash happens.

Comment: You have to exclude from obfuscation all classes that you use via reflection. In your case, you have to edit the file `proguard-rules.pro` and add the lines `-keep class com.someCompany.network..** { *; }` and `-keep class com.tradestation.network..** { *; }`;

Comment: @anemomylos Yes, that's already been added :)
Edit: wait ... nevermind other classes from Network file have been added but not the IndicatorDefinitions class

Comment: Have you check the NullPointerException on line 15? com.someCompany.XXX.MainActivity$g.getView(MainActivity.java:15)

Comment: @anemomylos Actually your first comment worked ... I thought I had it added to my proguard file but it was other classes in that File that was added but not that particular one IndicatorDefinitions. I wonder why this is happening all of sudden and not the other builds. Thank you so much!

Comment: Because in the other build you use `minifyEnabled false`.